# 403 forbidden when deploying symfony application on a Shared Web Hosting

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, http-status-code-403, shared-hosting

I'm trying to deploy my symfony app on a Shared Web Hosting server, so without any SSH access.
I've followed this tutorial : https://medium.com/@runawaycoin/deploying-symfony-4-application-to-shared-hosting-with-just-ftp-access-e65d2c5e0e3d

But i've done until the end and my homepage returns me just a 403 error, and every other url gets me a 404.

It looks like i've got to modify my .htaccess file, but apache-pack doesn't create one for me and the things i've found on internet doesn't work.

Does anyone can help me ?
Thanks

Comment: It seems your problem is from Apache (or nginx). Show us your host configuration.
Your virtualhost should be like this example : https://gist.github.com/tattali/58564a8c7233098fd207bcf42ed14821#apache-virtualhosts

Comment: I can't access any file on my servor as i can't connect to SSH.
Am i supposed to put those lines in my .htaccess file ?